# Update specific part of firebase database swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a hard time trying to figure out, how I can change/update a specific part of my firebase database through swift. To give you an example of how my firebase database is structured, here you have a photo:
[image]

I am trying to update the likesForPost +1 everytime someone hits the like button that I have in my tableViewController. The important part is that every likesForPost should not be updates, just the one where the button is. I hope you understand my situation and that you can help me :-)

**My struct**

```
struct Sweet {
    let key: String!
    let content: String!
    let addedByUser: String!
    let profilePhoto: String!
    var likesForPost: String!
    let itemRef: FIRDatabaseReference?



    init (content: String, addedByUser: String, profilePhoto: String!, likesForPost: String!, key: String = "") {
        self.key = key
        self.content = content
        self.addedByUser = addedByUser
        self.profilePhoto = profilePhoto
        self.likesForPost = likesForPost
        self.itemRef = nil
    }

    init (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key
        itemRef = snapshot.ref

        if let theFeedContent = snapshot.value!["content"] as? String {
            content = theFeedContent
        } else {
            content = ""
        }

        if let feedUser = snapshot.value!["addedByUser"] as? String {
            addedByUser = feedUser
        } else {
            addedByUser = ""
        }

        if let feedPhoto = snapshot.value!["profilePhoto"] as? String! {
            profilePhoto = feedPhoto
        } else {
            profilePhoto = ""
        }

        if let feedLikes = snapshot.value!["likesForPost"] as? String! {
            likesForPost = feedLikes
        } else {
            likesForPost = "0"
        }

    }

    func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
        return ["content":content, "addedByUser":addedByUser, "profilePhoto":profilePhoto!, "likesForPost":likesForPost]
    }
}
```

**My UITableViewController**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import FBSDKCoreKit

class feedTableViewController: UITableViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var loadingSpinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!


    var facebookProfileUrl = ""
    var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var updates = [Sweet]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadingSpinner.startAnimating()

        dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items")
        startObersvingDB()

    }

    func startObersvingDB() {
        dbRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            var newUpdates = [Sweet]()

            for update in snapshot.children {
                let updateObject = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newUpdates.append(updateObject)

            }

            self.updates = newUpdates
            self.tableView.reloadData()


        }) { (error: NSError) in
            print(error.description)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }




    @IBAction func addToFeed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let feedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "New update", message: "Enter your update", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        feedAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField:UITextField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Your update"
        }
        feedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            if let feedContent = feedAlert.textFields?.first?.text {


                if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
                    let name = user.displayName
                    //let photoUrl = user.photoURL




                    let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
                    if(accessToken != nil) //should be != nil
                    {

                        let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id"], tokenString: accessToken.tokenString, version: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
                        req.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error : NSError!) -> Void in
                            if(error == nil)
                            {
                                let userId: String! = result.valueForKey("id") as? String!
                                let userID = userId
                                self.facebookProfileUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large"

                                let likes = "0"

                                let feed = Sweet(content: feedContent, addedByUser: name!, profilePhoto: self.facebookProfileUrl, likesForPost: likes)
                                let feedRef = self.dbRef.child(feedContent.lowercaseString)

                                feedRef.setValue(feed.toAnyObject())




                            }
                            else
                            {
                                print("error \(error)")
                            }
                        })
                    }



                    // LAV FEEDCONTENT OM TIL OGSÅ AT MODTAGE PROFIL BILLEDE URL I STRING OG GIV SÅ facebookProfileUrl STRING LIGE HERUNDER I feed







                } else {
                    // No user is signed in.
                }
            }
        }))

        self.presentViewController(feedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }





    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return updates.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:updateTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! updateTableViewCell


        let update = updates[indexPath.row]

        //cell.textLabel?.text = update.content
        //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = update.addedByUser
        cell.nameLabel.text = update.addedByUser
        cell.updateLabel.text = update.content
        cell.likesLabel.text = "\(update.likesForPost) hi-fives"


        if update.profilePhoto! != "" {
        if let url = NSURL(string: update.profilePhoto!) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                cell.picView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                cell.picView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.picView.frame.size.width/2
                cell.picView.clipsToBounds = true

            }        
        }
        } else {
            print("Empty facebookProfileUrl")
        }





        loadingSpinner.stopAnimating()

        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: Avoid using same names for variable declaration and parameters in init. Its confusing and might stumble into an error later.

Comment: @Dravidian I'm not sure what is normal in Swift, but in most other languages (definitely Java, Android, JavaScript) it is idiomatic to name constructor parameters after the fields that they initialize.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that was just a personal note. I would declare a var like `key_structVar` and initialise it with a parameter name `key`.Altho nothing is wrong doing that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your struct to include one more variable (lets say `let path : String!`)that will include the value of the node key retrieved from your DB(megaTest or test).

**Your Struct**

```
   struct Sweet {
let key: String!
let content: String!
let addedByUser: String!
let profilePhoto: String!
var likesForPost: String!
let itemRef: FIRDatabaseReference?
let path : String! 


init (content: String, addedByUser: String, profilePhoto: String!, likesForPost: String!, key: String = "",dataPath : String!) {
    self.key = key
    self.content = content
    self.addedByUser = addedByUser
    self.profilePhoto = profilePhoto
    self.likesForPost = likesForPost
    self.itemRef = nil
    self.path = dataPath
}

init (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    itemRef = snapshot.ref
    path  = key 
    if let theFeedContent = snapshot.value!["content"] as? String {
        content = theFeedContent
    } else {
        content = ""
    }

    if let feedUser = snapshot.value!["addedByUser"] as? String {
        addedByUser = feedUser
    } else {
        addedByUser = ""
    }

    if let feedPhoto = snapshot.value!["profilePhoto"] as? String! {
        profilePhoto = feedPhoto
    } else {
        profilePhoto = ""
    }

    if let feedLikes = snapshot.value!["likesForPost"] as? String! {
        likesForPost = feedLikes
    } else {
        likesForPost = "0"
    }

}

func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
    return ["content":content, "addedByUser":addedByUser, "profilePhoto":profilePhoto!, "likesForPost":likesForPost,"pathInTheDB" : path]
    }
}
```

In **`cellForIndexPath`** just add this

```
  cell. pathDB = self.structArray![indexPath.row].path
```

Modify your customCell class like this

```
class customTableViewCell : UITableViewCell{

    var pathDB : String! //megaTest or test

     @IBAction func likeBtn(sender : UIButton!){

             //Update like's
         }
      }
```

For updating the value you can use either **`runTransactionBlock`**:-

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(pathDB).child("likesForPost").runTransactionBlock({ (likes: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
      // Set value and report transaction success
        likes.value = likes.value as! Int + 1
        return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(likes)
      }) { (err, bl, snap) in
        if let error = error {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
      }
```

**Or** observe that node with `.observeSingleEventOfType`, retrieve the snap and then update

```
let parentRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(pathDB).child("likesForPost")   
parentRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value,withBlock : {(snap) in

 if let nOfLikes = snap.value as? Int{

          parentRef.setValue(nOfLikes+1)

    }

})
```

Comment: If I do that, then it gives me an error `Cannot invoke initializer for type..` my struct?

Comment: @Dradivian I updated the struct so no error would show. The problem is now, when I click the like button nothing is changed..

Comment: It is getting the pathDB though, I could see that with a print when tapping the button

Comment: Try using `.observeSingleEventOfType` because i just checked, and it worked... make sure you are referencing your DB correctly.Also try printing `pathDB` by cliking different cell's like button and check if you are getting correct corresponding `pathDB`.